# Verb meaning to be evidence for

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb meaning ‘to be (non-conclusive) evidence for’? That is, like ‘prove’ but weaker.

Comment: [**Allude, imply, indicate, infer, insinuate, intimate, suggest**,etc.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/imply) The exact context might help identify the most suitable term if you're not happy with **evidence** as a verb.

Comment: *Deduce* or *hypothesise*?

Comment: Voting to close, since there's no evidence to suggest the OP tried consulting a thesaurus.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest *suggest*.

> The data suggest that the law of supply and demand is still intact.

Or perhaps *support*.

> The data support the notion that "There no such thing as a free lunch."

Or as suggested by @reinierpost (with props to @zx8754): *indicate*.

> The data indicate a positive correlation between smoking and incidence of lung cancer (p<.05).

Comment: Another option is *indicate*.

Comment: @reinierpost, good word; why not propose as an answer? "The p-values *indicate* that smoking is correlated with incidence of lung cancer, but does not prove that smoking causes lung cancer."

Comment: You might as well add it to yours. I like your other suggestions.